Drop Postgres Replication slot warnings
I'm trying to drop the replication slot. I got the below warnings, so what are these all about? and Any action is required?
postgres=> SELECT pg_drop_replication_slot('abcd_firehose_s3_stream_slot');
WARNING:  could not open directory "pg_replslot/abcd_firehose_s3_stream_slot": No such file or directory
WARNING:  could not remove directory "pg_replslot/abcd_firehose_s3_stream_slot"
pg_drop_replication_slot
(1 row)
Slot has been dropped, but should we worry about those warnings?
